# Azure Cognitive Search - Do sematic search configuration support binding content field to content type in a Edm.ComplexType?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, semantic-search

Does Azure cognitive search sematic search configuration support binding content field to content type in a Edm.ComplexType? I have an index which have a collection of complex types. Each item in the complex type has a content string field that has text extracted from documents. If possible, I would like to enable semantic search for this content.

Can not configure semantic content field in Azure portal. Content field from complex types does not show up in dropdown field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic Search supports Semantic Configurations over the following field types:  Edm.String and subfields of Edm.ComplexType as per [Create a semantic configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/semantic-how-to-query-request?tabs=portal%2Cportal-query#2---create-a-semantic-configuration). If your index already contains an Edm.ComplexType field with the respective sub-fields you will see them in the drop down accordingly. Example:

[image]

If for any reason the existing sub-fields of an Edm.ComplexType field are not showing up for you in the portal and you are meeting all pre-requisites (such as having a Standard+ SKU service and having already the field in your index, I suggest you to [open an Azure support case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have created a separate index without a complex type and in this index the semantic configuration works as expected. I will look into opening a support case.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others that stumble upon this. String subfields of Collection(Edm.ComplexType) are not currently supported. The original post mentions that they are using an array of complex types.

> **Across all semantic configuration properties, the fields you assign
> must be:**
>
> - Attributed as searchable and retrievable.
> - Strings of type Edm.String, Edm.ComplexType, or
>   Collection(Edm.String).
>
> String subfields of Collection(Edm.ComplexType) fields aren't
> currently supported in semantic ranking, captions, or answers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/semantic-how-to-query-request